# Does OpenGLES supports all OS?

Tags: android, c++, ios, macos, egl

I tried to make video editor program using [OpenGLES](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/) and I want to support both mobile and desktop (Windows, OSX) so I plan to use the shader file and part of gl library.

For the details:

1. If I develop a Windows application and use the EGL library, can I support all of the computer? If not, how can I support it without changing my code?
2. Does the EAGL support GLES code?
3. I have used the EGL library developed by AMD. Why does this work also on say an Intel CPU and Nvidia graphics card even if library doesn't match each CPU company?

Comment: Looks like it depends on the version and vendor: https://www.khronos.org/conformance/adopters/conformant-products#opengles